# Como uso Expresion Regular en esta forma?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una interrogante surgido a partir de una solución. Uso 
*Tampermonkey* para **deseleccionar** archivos de una lista; funciona bien, pero me pregunto si podría aplicarle **expresión regular** para ampliar más su objetivo.

```html
<div class="well">
  <h2>Select you files</h2>
  <table id="list-files" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="checked"></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="0" ""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="tuSITIO.com.txt"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>34.0 iB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="1" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.mkv"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>8.8 GiB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="2" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.nfo"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>5.4 KiB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Acá vemos un ejemplo donde el `Script` hace su trabajo correctamente y, en este caso, desmarca el archivo `"tuSITIO.com.txt"`.

Mi `Script`:

```
var inp=$("tr input");
var r="tuSITIO.com.txt";
for (i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) { 
 if(inp[i].value == r){
  inp[i-1].checked = false;
 }
}
```

Este `Script` (by @Bryro) desmarca cualquier archivo que se cargue a una lista funciona muy bien para valores exactos como el ejemplo `"tuSITIO.com.txt"`

Ahora... ¿Cómo podría ampliar su objetivo usando expresiones regulares?
Supongamos que no deseo incluir ningún archivo `.txt`, `.nfo`, `.url` o `.website`. ¿Es posible eso?

Por ej desmarcar archivos tipo:

```
metadata.nfo
tu.sitio.nfo
qwerty(23).nfo
1a2b3c4d.url
```

He visto algunos como: `"([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";` se me ocurre que tal vez poniendo: `(nfo|url|url|website)` podría resultar pero no se como podría proceder, agradezco su ayuda y/o información, saludos. Recuerden es para *Tampermonkey* similar a *Greasemonkey*.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que explícitamente solicitaste expresiones regulares, basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190933/4579817) logré esto:

```
/^.+\.([^.]|js|jpg|srt)$/
```

A partir de él puedes filtrar un arreglo de nombres de archivo con extensiones (o excluirlos) fácilmente con el [método filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter). Aquí hay un ejemplo:

```js
const files = [
    "The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.jpg",
    "texto.txt",
    "index.html",
    "The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.srt",
];

files
  .filter(file => /^.+\.([^.]|js|jpg|html)$/.test(file))
  .forEach(file => console.log(file));
```

Entonces, puedes usarlo así para resolver tu problema (con algunos cambios para mejorar la legibilidad):

```
const inp = $("tr input");
//Solo en caso de que el resultado no sea un objeto Array
const files = Array.from(inp);
files
  .filter(({value: filename}) => {
      const extension = getFileExtension(filename);
      return isValidExtension(extension);
  })
  .forEach(item => item.checked = false);

function getFileExtension(filename) {
  const ext = /^.+\.([^.]+)$/.exec(filename);
  return ext == null ? "" : ext[1];
}

function isValidExtension(extension) {
  return /^js|jpg|html$/.test(extension)
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, sabés.. soy muy nuevo en esto, honestamente no se como podría aplicarlo a mi Tampermonkey :( intento cargar mi `HTML` mas tu código (con lo que yo creo -evidentemente mal- sería la adaptacion) http://jsfiddle.net/ y no me sale!. agradecería una ayuda de cualquiera q lea esto y me de una mano. muchas gracias Juan!

Comment: @Stack_qwerty no olvides marcar como respuesta si resolvió tu duda. Respecto a cómo aplicarlo pues... honestamente no estoy familiarizado con el funcionamiento de Tampermonkey, así que no sabría orientarte :( pero si llegas a tener dudas de un problema específico, deja una pregunta y la comunidad verá de qué forma se te puede ayudar :)

Comment: Tampermonkey funciona muy parecido a http://jsfiddle.net/ tu cargas un `HTML` mas un `script` y a continuación muestra el resultado con la modificación q supone el codigo personalizado. yo te pido q ingreses a http://jsfiddle.net/4gZAT/ (borra lo q tiene) y coloca el `HTML` q puse d ejemplo mas tu `scrip` y veas si tu código hace lo q pregunto aquí, obviamente tu sabes como adaptar el código exageradamente mas q yo.